# Start Scene in a single view application

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created a riddle game in IOS using a single view application - not as a SpriteKit application. When the user opens the app it automatically jumps into to the game, which is a bad UX. I have seen how to add a start scene in a SpriteKit but things are different on a single view app.

I was able to add another view to my app and go between the Start scene view to the game view, but this is not what I need. How am I supposed to add a start scene to a single view application?

Comment: imo it's easier to use UIKit from a spritekit app than SK in a UIKit app. You can use spritekit in a storyboard (crazy) and present it as normal, or in code you need to create a `SKView` subclass then load that view, then have the skview `.presentScene`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way to do it -

1. Add a new view controller
2. Create a view controller swift file (file -> new file-> cocoa touch class (subclass of UIViewController)
3. Add the button to the view controller and connect it to the swift file as an action button
4. Set the view as the initial view controller (click on the view and in the attribute inspector mark the 'Is initial View Controller'
5. Right click and drag the button to the view you would like it to show
6. Click show and then a segue will be created
7. Give the segue an identifier
8. Add the following code in the corresponding place in the new swift file -

**performSegue(withIdentifier: "playSegue", sender: self)**